# Trying to download remote image with php

Tags: php

I've trying to download remote images(from more than one site) but any of these codes worked

allow_url_fopen is on but these code will return 0 bytes

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = 'teste.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

or

```
copy('http://example.com/image.php', 'teste.jpg');
```

When I use curl(that is enabled on host) this error appears:

Error: The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error: Empty reply from server

curl code :

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('teste,jpg, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Edit: Tried following curl opt too:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $lfile);
```

site is hosted by 000webhost, and after trying my whole day with differents codes I had to use a proxy to access my site because it was blocking me

Edit 2:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"h.mhcdn.net/store/manga/10738/thumb_cover.jpg?v=1476422230");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
//die("here1");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
die("here2");
file_put_contents("test.jpg", $data);
die("here3");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, "test.jpg");
```

Tried code above but it wont reach  "die("here2");"(page wont load) only the  die("here1");

Edit 3:

```
$url = "http://h.mhcdn.net/store/manga/10738/thumb_cover.jpg?v=1476422230";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
        //die("here1");
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        file_put_contents("local_file.jpg", $data);
        die("here2");
```

Can't reach here2, only here1

Edit 4: here's the problem: port 80 has been blocked for outgoing connections at 000web : https://www.habschned.com/000webhost-com-blocking-port-80-for-outbound-traffic-no-more-curl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's pretty obvious, but did you try to open the URL in your browser? Can you see the image?

If the answer to the above is YES (most likely), most likely the remote party is blocking scripts from fetching the resource. The solution is to use cURL emulating as best as possible the behaviour of a regular browser, in terms of HTTP headers.

I would start from the most obvious ones which are CURLOPT_USERAGENT and CURLOPT_USERAGENT, set them at the values they expect and you should be fine. More complex access controls involve cookies and sessions, which is more complicated because you would have to fetch the referring page, store the cookie, and send it while fetching the resource.

**UPDATE:**

While the above is true, it was not the problem the asker had, this simple script should work as-is:

```
$url = "http://h.mhcdn.net/store/manga/10738/thumb_cover.jpg?v=1476422230";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("local_file.jpg", $data);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to open the url, and tried with different remote images. tried following code too :

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $lfile);`

Comment: If you can provide a sample URL I could try it out

Comment: Thank you! Here's on of the url I tried : http://h.mhcdn.net/store/manga/10738/thumb_cover.jpg?v=1476422230                               or http://h.mhcdn.net/store/manga/15063/cover.jpg?v=1474601221    but I tried some randoms images from google too

Comment: Wait, I think I misinterpreted your question. Your code just works, you need to drop CURLOPT_FILE, you just want CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, that way the `$data = curl_exec($ch)` will return you the content of the image, you just need to file_put_contents("test.jpg", $data) to save it

Comment: Tried it and didn't work   =(  look  edit 2, please. Is there any thing else i'm missing?

Comment: Even with "http://" it doesn't work: Error: The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error: Empty reply from server.    See Edit 3 pls

Comment: I'm afraid you have a problem with your PHP/Server environment. The script in "Edit 3" works.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you have any guess what's wrong on the server? Cause I took a look and saw that curl is enabled and allow_url_fopen On
allow_url_include Off   (cURL support enabled
cURL Information libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5)

Comment: perhaps your server is configured to block outgoing TCP connections? Some hosting web servers are configured this way to prevent abuse, try contacting your ISP, or try to run the script on another server.

Comment: that's it, thank you for the guess. I searched for "block outgoing tcp connections" and found : "Anyway, should your website use cURL to fetch data from an external website via port 80 then it won’t work anymore because of port 80 now being blocked. There isn’t a solution to this really, except you being able to fetch the data through another port or switching hosts." https://www.habschned.com/000webhost-com-blocking-port-80-for-outbound-traffic-no-more-curl/